# how to search Xcode doc set

Tags: xcode, search, full-text-search, document

Here's another really stupid question. Xcode has a Developer Documentation window. There are sections dedicated to sorting the results of a language reference search.

There's no search bar. No button that says "Search for:".  No magnifying glass.

What am I looking for? Google doesn't understand my question, and I thought I'd ask you before Wolfram Alpha comes out tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sure do see a search bar.

From Xcode:

- Click on Help->Documentation
- In the top right of the Developer Documentation window on the toolbar there's a Search bar.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, thank you rein. To be more specific, its that anonymous grey oblong button at the top right corner that hides this search bar.

Comment: That's the show/hide toolbar button (which has the same effect as View -> Show/Hide Toolbar); it will have the same effect in every application.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but I've always found that Google is able to find the relevant documentation faster than Xcode's built-in documentation. I just keep a browser window open, and set up the default search box to use google, with the site limited to developer.apple.com:

> http://www.google.com/search?q=SOMETHING+site%3Adeveloper.apple.com